# Issue with javascript date object

Tags: javascript, date

I am facing a weird problem while initializes javascript date object,no matter what I initialize to it shows the date as 1 JAN 1970 05:30;

this is the way I try to initialize

```
var d=new date(27-02-1989);
```

alerting 'd' shows 1 JAN 1970.....,also sometimes it takes  a date passed from the database but in the format as mm/dd/yyyy not in the format I want i.e dd/mm/yyyy

This problem has suddenly popped-up, as everything was working smooth couple of days ago,but today after opening the project (after 2 days) this issue is irritating me

Comment: 1st Jan 1970 is the start point of unixtime - usually an indication that something is evaluating to zero or false - try new Date(false) in your console

Comment: have you tried date("27-02-1989"); ?

Comment: yeah the quotes works,but it still takes the format as mm/dd/yyyy how do I change this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// Transform your european date in RFC compliant date (american)
var date = '27-02-1989'.split('-').reverse().join('-');

// And this works
var d = new Date( date );
```

Proof:

[image: Proof]

Comment: the quotes work but can you tell me how do I get my original default format back i.e dd/mm/yyyy

Comment: uh? I thought that was the original format? I'm not sure this is what you need, but here goes: `'1989-02-27'.split('-').reverse().join('-');`. I strongly suggest you understand what this code does.

Comment: yeah I got the working with string,thanks,and yes it was the original format,someone may have changed the regional settings,thats why I am getting mm.dd.yyyy as default

Comment: -1  d/m/y is not "American" format, that might be m/d/y. Do not use Date.parse to parse strings, it is specified as implementation dependent in ES3, one format of ISO8601 in ES5 and there is no one format that works in "popular" browsers. Manually parse the string.

Comment: need some help manipulating the string ,the string which I have is 
dd-mm-yyyy hh:mm:ss ,I just want to reverse and join mm and dd,the code you have provided reverses the whole string to hh:mm:ss yyyy-mm-dd,

I want the output as mm-dd-yyyy.....also it would be better if I can somehow tell javascript to except dd/mm/yyyy format

Comment: Otherwise, Date.parse can be shimmed quite easily (using manual parsing). It's worth implementing the shim if the code is cleaner. https://gist.github.com/303249

Comment: @Snedden27 knowing how `split()` works, you should be able to come up with your own solution.

Comment: @FlorianMargaine yes I was just being lazy :)

Answer (score 2):

I see you've accepted an answer, but it isn't the best you can do. There is no one format that is parsed correctly by all browsers in common use, the accepted answer will fail in IE 8 at least.

The only safe way to convert a string to a date is to parse it, e.g.

```
var s = '27-02-1989';
var bits = s.split('-');
var date = new Date(bits[2], --bits[1], bits[0]);
```

Answer (score 1):

according to [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) you can try:

```
new Date()
new Date(milliseconds)
new Date(dateString)
new Date(year, month, day [, hour, minute, second, millisecond ])
```

so for your case use (**edit**: You need to remember that months are zero based)

```
var d = new Date(1989,01,27);
```

pleas notice - use `Date` (capital D)

Comment: You need to remember that months are zero based: new Date(1989,02,27) will give him the 27th March, not February

Answer (score 1):

You're doing an initialization with a negative integer value (`27-02-1989 == -1964`). The `Date` object's constructor takes arguments listed [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date).

If you want to pass strings, they need to be in an RFC2822-compliant format (see [here](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2822#page-14)).

Comment: Wrong reference, ISO8601 is the only format specified in [ES5](http://es5.github.com/#x15.9.1.15), but it's not supported by all browsers in common use. ECMAScript ed3 did not specify any format, it was implementation dependent.

Comment: Thanks, you're right. I didn't verify the other format myself. It's probably the best way to parse the input string to numbers and use them for the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

First of all

```
var d=new date(27-02-1989);
```

is totaly wrong expression in javascript, moreover even if we rewrites it more correctly:

```
var d=new Date('27-02-1989');
```

there is no way to parse this date string natively in js.

Here solutions you can try:

- transform string to ISO8601: YYYY-mm-dd, this can be parsed by most modern broswers, or you can use many js libraries for polyfill
- split string string by '-' and then use Date constructor function `new Date(year, month-1, day)`
- split string and use `setDate, setMonth, setYear` method on `new Date()` object

  Note that in last two methods you need to deduct 1 from month value, because month is zero-based (0 stands for January, 11 for December)